# problem with python requests while using proxies

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, proxies

I am trying to scrape a website using python requests. We can only scrape the website using proxies so I implemented the code for that. However its banning all my requests even when i am using proxies, So I used a website https://api.ipify.org/?format=json to check whether proxies working properly or not. I found it showing my original IP even while using proxies. The code is below

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

import string, random

import requests

import sys



http = []

#loading http into the list
with open(sys.argv[1],"r",encoding = "utf-8") as data:

    for i in data:
        http.append(i[:-1])
    data.close()

url = "https://api.ipify.org/?format=json"

def fetch(session, url):
    
for i in range(5):
    
      
                proxy = {'http': 'http://'+random.choice(http)}

               
                try:
                        with session.get(url,proxies = proxy, allow_redirects=False) as response:
                            print("Proxy : ",proxy," | Response : ",response.text)
                            break
                except:
                        pass



# @timer(1, 5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor:
        with requests.Session() as session:
            executor.map(fetch, [session] * 100, [url] * 100)
            executor.shutdown(wait=True)
```

I tried a lot but didn't understand how my ip address is getting shown instead of the proxy ipv4. You will find output of the code here https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mk03j.jpg

Comment: Try to add also `https` key with same value to you `proxy` dictionary.

Comment: Awesome. Now it actually showing the proxy ip address. I think I should only use https here. However when I tried the same code without using multi threading it actually worked.

Comment: Better to use 3 keys (`'http'`, `'https'` and `'ftp'`) always, it will be guarantee that `requests` will use proxy anyway. And it's really weird that using multithreading affects on third-part library, probably there's something else.

Comment: Yeah I will consider it from next time (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you have set proxy for `http` and sending request to website which uses `https`. Solution is simple:

```
proxies = dict.fromkeys(('http', 'https', 'ftp'), 'http://' + random.choice(http))
# You can set proxy for session
session.proxies.update(proxies)
response = session.get(url)
# Or you can pass proxy as argument
response = session.get(url, proxies=proxies)
```

Comment: can we add socks4 and socks5  without creating a separate dictionary?

Comment: @Lakshmipathi, to add socks proxy support you need to install `PySocks` and specify protocol with version. Examples: `'socks4://127.0.0.1:9000'`, `'socks4a://127.0.0.1:9001'` *(send DNS query over proxy)*, `'socks5://127.0.0.1:9002'`,  `'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9003'` *(send DNS query over proxy)*.